# Should I use Joomla or go purely HTML

Tags: html, joomla, content-management-system, web-development-server

I am currently building a project ecommerce website (for an assigmnet), and would like some tips from the experts around. Should I go for a frontend based on purely HTML,CSS and JS (say with a jquery framework) or should I include a CMS such as Joomla in order to be able to manage better the content ? I am not a very experienced web developer so there is quite a learning curve I have to go through in this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have a domain name or plan to have one but… 
There are many web hosting provider that propose built-in solution for e-commerce.

You talk about Joomla but there is also many other CMS that allow you do create e-commerce pages. A Wordpress module can do it with, for example, which I personally think as easier to use.

By the way, if you got enough time and motivation, I recommend you to search for documentation and to experiment the most you can on a custom-coded frontend.
I don't know what is your level in the HTML/CSS/JS languages, but you'll gain experience and that's always usefull.

Comment: No this is a local project, I am using XAMPP and the scope is the learn web design technologies so I do not wish to use a ready made solution.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use HTML, CSS, JS. They are the three major languages that make up most of the web. It allows a lot of flexibility.